# Coverting int to string

Tags: ios, swift

```
(cell.viewWithTag(24) as! UILabel).text = "\(tmpSeasonName)\(String((path)["seasoncategoryno"] as? Int ?? 0)): \(tmpEpisodeName)\(String((path) ["episodeno"] as? Int ?? 0))"
```

I want to show season number and episode number side by side (Season 1 : Episode 5)like this but it was showing like season 1: Episode 0. Episode number is not updating.

```
["carouselidgroupnametvshownamepublished": SeriesEpisodeThe Qimmah Showtrue, "maturityrating":  , "productsizes":  , "episodeno": 1, "featuredpublish": truetrue, "releasedate": 2018-06-11, "publishparent": truefalse]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part of your code is the issue:
`(String((path) ["episodeno"] as? Int ?? 0)`

You are nil coalescing `"episodeno"` as an `Int` , defaulting (`??`) to `0`.

You are getting 0 because the value for `episodeno` is either `nil` or it is not convertible to `Int` and is therefore defaulting to `0`

Answer (score 1):

For Typecasting method  using the coding is to convert int to String

Example :

```
var imgArry = [String: AnyObject]()

let dict: [String: AnyObject] =  ["ID":1 as AnyObject,"IMAGE":#imageLiteral(resourceName: "image_name")]

imgArry.append(dict)
```

to compare for select row for detect id

```
dictDataInfo:[String: AnyObject]

if dictDataInfo["ID"] as! String == dict["ID"] as! String{
    Print (i)
}
```